# Can't download PDF invoice, getting a "network failure" error. Magento ver. 2.3.4

Tags: magento2.3.4, invoice-pdf

I am trying to download an invoice via "Print PDF" in one of my orders. But I'm getting the error "Failed - Network error" in Chrome, Firefox and Edge.

How can I fix this so I will be able to download an invoice again?
If I need to facilitate more information, let me know.